# Javascript calculation bug

Tags: javascript, math

is there a better way to multiply and divide figures than using the `*` and `/` ?

There is a strange behavior in Chrome Firefox and Internet Explorer using those operaters:

```
x1 = 9999.8
x1 * 100 = 999979.9999999999
x1 * 100 / 100 = 9999.8
x1 / 100 = 99.99799999999999
```

http://jsbin.com/ekoye3/

I am trying to round down the user input with `parseInt ( x1 * 100 ) / 100` and the result for `9999.8` is `9999.79`

Should I use another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's no bug. You may want to check out:

- [Is JavaScript’s math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

Integer arithmetic in floating-point is exact, so decimal representation errors can be avoided by scaling. For example:

```
x1 = 9999.8;                            // Your example
console.log(x1 * 100);                  // 999979.9999999999
console.log(x1 * 100 / 100);            // 9999.8
console.log(x1 / 100);                  // 99.99799999999999

x1 = 9999800;                           // Your example scaled by 1000
console.log((x1 * 100) / 10000);        // 999980
console.log((x1 * 100 / 100) / 10000);  // 9999.8
console.log((x1 / 100) / 10000);        // 99.998
```

Comment: integer arithmetic is only exact up to a point, eventially 1 ULP != 1

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [toFixed()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) method:

```
var a = parseInt ( x1 * 100 ) / 100;
var result = a.toFixed( 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks - didn't know `.toFixed` it works great. However you probably meant `x1.toFixed( 2 )` instead - didn't you?

Answer (score 1):

[You may want to check this](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). If you want to do computation on numbers which represent money, you should count cents and use integers.